# Replace YEAR part with custom year in SQL Server Select statement

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

I am working with SQL Server and a table containing DOB [Date Of Birth] column.

I have saved a value in table against that column, that is = '**May 5 1988 12:00AM**', but I need '**May 5 1900 12:00AM**' when I select the column.

I have this basic query:

```
SELECT CAST(dbo.contact.dob AS VARCHAR) AS DOBFROM dbo.contact
```

The result is  `May 5 1988 12:00AM`

Any help?

Comment: So you always need the year to be 1900, regardless of what it is? What version of SQLServer are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to replace the custom year then this might help you. Here `GETDATE()` is your `datecolumn`.

```
DECLARE @CustomYear = '1900'
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(MAX)),DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()),@CustomYear)
```

This gives me output as,

> Mar 17 1900  4:12AM

Answer (score 1):

A simple date math:

```
select dateadd(year, -datediff(year, '19000101', getdate()), getdate())
```

(where `getdate()` stands for your table's column).

You might have a problem with leap years, though.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can help you out, i think what you need is:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, (1900-(DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.contact.dob))), dbo.contact.dob ) AS DOB FROM dbo.contact
```

[DATEADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) and [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174420.aspx) will do the trick

Comment: Your query throws error The [DATEADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) requires 3 arguments also it displays wrong answer based on OP's requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 2 years like

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(year,2,dbo.contact.dob) AS VARCHAR) AS DOB
FROM dbo.contact
```

This will add you  years so you will get for May 5 1988 12:00AM -> added 2 years like May 5 1990 12:00AM